# Combining django-rest-framework with regular HTTP application

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am reworking an application since it would benefit from having a RESTful backend. I feel that I have somehow taken a wrong turn by combining the rest API and the regular HTTP into a single app.

This means they share the urls.py and the views.py and are competing for urls and stuff gets mixed up (like applying the format_suffix_patterns to all urls).

I hope to get an opinion (or confirmation) that it would be a much better plan to roll it into two separate applications.

old plan

```
manage.py
/project
/combinedapp
    admin.py
    models.py
    urls.py       # both types of urls
    views.py      # both views
```

new plan

```
manage.py
/project
/restapp
    urls.py      # only the rest endpoints
    views.py     # api stuff: links to httpapp.models
/httpapp
    admin.py     # like a normal app
    models.py
    urls.py
    views.py
```

As you can tell I am new to this and trying to prevent shooting myself in the foot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided to refactor the project following the new plan. These are the results:

- It was very easy to do: approximately 15 minutes of work to make a
  new app, move some files and split to content.
- Protip: the new app is
  for the rest api. That way you conserve the existing table names and
  such.
- Results are just fine: clear separation of concerns and urls.

Conclusion never mix a rest-api with an HTTP app.